# Nginx service is running successfully but returns apache default page?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration, apache2, configuration-management

i installed nginx on server(ubuntu 16.04) which already had apache2 and,
done this following configuration,

> ->changed apache port 80 to 8888 so nginx would listen to 80
>    ->restarted apache and nginx in sequence.

still getting apache default page when i type http://localhost
i also stopped apache2 service and restarted nginx service to ensure only once server run at time but still getting apache default page on localhost request!!! which should be actually nginx default page cuase apache service is not running anymore.

**One thing i found suspicious is 'htcacheclean' process is running,is that responsible for the returning Apache page?!**

how this is happening is strange for me!!
kindly share hint if you ever faced this kind of issue.

> ss -tlnp return following for the port 80
>   State       Recv-Q   Send-Q         Local Address:Port     Peer Address:Port
>   LISTEN    0              0                              *:80                                                     **:* *

**ss -tlnp | grep nginx command output shows nginx**

[image: ss -tlnp | grep nginx command output]

Comment: On what port does `nginx` run in your machine? It defaults to apache because `apache2` uses port `80` by default. How does your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` look like? What does `ss -tlnp` return or rather, what does `lsof -i :80` return` when apache is not active and `nginx` is.?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Yes cleared cache and checked @RichardSmith!

Comment: ss -tlnp command output updated in question  @val0x00ff

Comment: @DexJ I need to know the service name on that port. Can you run `ss -tlnp | grep nginx` or `lsof -i :80`. If `lsof` command is not available you can install it using `aptitude install lsof`

Comment: can you run `curl -I http://<your address>` please, so you can see if the webserver answering is nginx or apache

Comment: You should check if Apache and Nginx have the same document root directory. In this case, check the document root directory (usually it is `/var/www/html/`) and if there is `index.html` file remove it, or rename it. Most likely it is the default `index.html` file created by Apache.

Comment: @val0x00ff updated ss -tlnp | grep nginx commnad output in question it says nginx

Comment: if this is not prod server , just disable apache server for a while and see the results.. as said if its still saving apachee default page its to do with index file as said by Rosehosting

Comment: after disabling apache and clearing browser cache and after verifying document root, still its there ? then go for clearing nigix cache.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx may be nigix is holding a copy !

Comment: @DiegoVelez it shows apache 2 while i am requesting but isn't that weird cause i checked > service --status-all and found apache process is not running...! but i found another related process  updated question plz check :)

Answer (score 2):

Its because nginx may have same **DocumentRoot** as apache and It's index.html is still in `/var/www/html`. I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue in my linux.
Solution is to purge apache2 entirely.
for me the command  - `sudo apt purge apache2`

Here is the complete solution to the problem-

1. use gunicorn to start your django site
2. edit nginx configurations to tell it to listen on another port except port 80

3.Boom solved.(Don't forget to restart nginx)

Here is how to- (my django site name is 'mysite'; replace it with yours(folder containing `wsgi` file.))

1. in your django site folder
   command:`gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application`
2. editing nginx -
   command: `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite_nginx.conf`
   with code:-

server {
listen 8001;
server_name 192.168.1.36;  # Your machine's local IP address

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;  # Gunicorn's default bind address
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

And then, create a symlink for it-
command: `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

3.Restart nginx service-
command: `sudo service nginx restart`
or
command: `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start`

Finally, it will be available to every device connected to your local network
use 'http://your_machine_ip:8001' to access it

Pardon me for beginner silly mistakes; I'm new to it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/562106)